# Volley retry if JSON request contains special status

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

My application uses search service, which takes a long time to return result. Service returns `{status : "not_ready"}` if results not ready and `{status: "ok"}`, if search finished.
Can I implement retries depending of content of JSON response in Volley framework?

Comment: How do you get the response now? Through an interface or just waiting until you get a response and continuing with the code?

Comment: I get response from Response.Listener on JsonObjectRequest object

Comment: Why not just resend the request of status comes back as "not_ready"